# How do I use Nokogiri to extract the text from this HTML and keep the <br> elements?

Tags: nokogiri

I have this string

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM \"http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml.dtd\">\n\n\n<en-note>\n<font size=\"5\">text_part_1</font><br><br>\n<font size=\"5\">text_part_2</font><br><br>\n<font size=\"5\">text_part_3</font>
```

I need to extract the text content, but also keep the `<br>` elements. So the result would be

```
text_part_1<br><br>text_part_2<br><br>text_part_3
```

How can I use Nokogiri to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is, your XML is illegal. `<br>` is unterminated; It should be `<br/>` in XML, or have a end-tag, i.e., `</br>`.

Nokogiri is raising errors when trying to parse the XML as a result. If you check the `errors` method after parsing you'll see something like:

```
[
#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Premature end of data in tag br line 7>,
#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Premature end of data in tag br line 7>,
#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Premature end of data in tag br line 6>,
#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Premature end of data in tag br line 6>,
#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Premature end of data in tag en-note line 5>
]
```

Fix that, and Nokogiri will be able to process the XML correctly. At that point, you'll be able to do something simple like:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM \"http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml.dtd\">


<en-note>
<font size=\"5\">text_part_1</font><br/><br/>
<font size=\"5\">text_part_2</font><br/><br/>
<font size=\"5\">text_part_3</font>
EOT

doc.search('br').each do |br|
  br.replace('##br##')
end


text = doc.content.gsub('##br##', '<br/>')
puts text
```

Here's the output with the corrected `br` tags:

```
text_part_1<br/><br/>
text_part_2<br/><br/>
text_part_3
```

The simplest way to fix the XML is to run some cleanup code before parsing it, like:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml.gsub('<br>', '<br/>'))
```

where `xml` is the variable containing your XML content.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
html =  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM \"http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml.dtd\">\n\n\n<en-note>\n<font size=\"5\">text_part_1</font><br><br>\n<font size=\"5\">text_part_2</font><br><br>\n<font size=\"5\">text_part_3</font>"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
str = ""
doc.traverse { |n| str << n.to_s if (n.name == "text" or n.name == "br") }
str #=> "text_part_1<br><br>text_part_2<br><br>text_part_3"
```